# Load specific .dart file depending on media

Tags: html, dart

I know it is possible to load a specific CSS file depending on media type, but is it possible to do the same for the dart file?

For example, i want to load a specific dart file depending on whether media type is "handheld" or "screen"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, it can be done but not through media.
The solution is to dynamically load the correct script:

```
<script>

  var scriptSrc = 'firstScript.dart';
  if (screen.width <= 800)
  scriptSrc = 'secondScript.dart';
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "application/dart";
  script.src = scriptSrc;
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.appendChild(script); 

</script>
```

Comment: Just like with JavaScript, the "media" can't control loading of those scripts. I can't think of anything else myself than what you have here. Actually, if I would do need this myself, I would always load the code, but within the code just do necessary checks (feature, screen size, etc. checks).